# Select from term_taxnomy table using AND

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have stucked with a situation, where i have to show posts on check and uncheck of the terms.

The posts having terms assigned. I have terms 'Area' and 'Cuisines' now i have to select the post which has the area 'XYZ' and cuisine 'ABC'.

The query i have tried :-

```
    SELECT p.ID, p.post_title 
      FROM wp_posts p 
 LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` t 
        ON p.ID = t.object_id 
 LEFT JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` tt 
        ON t.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
     WHERE tt.term_id IN (".$area.") 
           OR tt.term_id IN (".$cuis.") 
  GROUP BY t.object_id 
    HAVING COUNT( t.term_taxonomy_id ) = 2 
     LIMIT 0,7
```

And the Structure of the wp_term_taxonomy is shown here :-

The problem is the single table and single column and apply the AND operator between the values.

wp_term_relationship

```
object_id  | wp_term_taxonomy_id | term_order
==============================================
   134     |       36            |    0
______________________________________________
   135     |       36            |    0
```

wp_posts

```
    ID     |    post_title       |
==================================
    1      |       Hello world!  |  
__________________________________
    2      |       Test          |
```

wp_term_taxnomy

```
  term_taxonomy_id  term_id     taxonomy    description     parent  count
        =============================================================================
          1                1            category     ------           0        2
```

Comment: can you give sample records that has the following columns used in your `select` statement?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, we have 3 tables:

```
| test1 |     | test1_to_test2 |         | test2 |
|-------+     +----------------|         +-------|
| id    |-----|  test1_id      |    +----|  id   |
              |  test2_id      |----+
```

Exactly the structure, that you have.

Content:

```
    test1
+----+-------+     
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | val1  |
|  2 | val2  |
+----+-------+

    test1_to_test2
|----------+----------|
| test1_id | test2_id |
|----------+----------|
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        2 |
|        2 |        1 |
|----------+----------|

 test2
|----+
| id |
|----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|----+
```

And we need to select values from test1 table, that have rows in test1_to_test2 with (test2_id = 1) AND (test2_id = 2). So, we want this:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | val1  |
+----+-------+
```

To do it we split the task into 2 subtasks:

1.Select `test1_id` from test1_to_test2, that has both rows present:

```
SELECT
    test1_id
FROM
    test1_to_test2
WHERE
    test1_to_test2.test2_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
    test1_id
HAVING
    COUNT(test1_id) = 2
```

2.Select the appropriate rows from test1, using the subquery and IN operator (it's the SQL, that we need):

```
SELECT
    test1.id,
    test1.`value`
FROM
    test1
WHERE
    test1.id IN
(
SELECT
    test1_id
FROM
    test1_to_test2
WHERE
    test1_to_test2.test2_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
    test1_id
HAVING
    COUNT(test1_id) = 2
)
```

We get what we need:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | val1  |
+----+-------+
```

Use the same approach with your tables, and you'll get the posts which have the area 'XYZ' and cuisine 'ABC'.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do two joins, one for each term:

```
    SELECT p.ID, p.post_title 
      FROM wp_posts p 
 LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` t 
        ON p.ID = t.object_id 
 LEFT JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` tarea
        ON t.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id and tt.term_id IN (".$area.") 
 LEFT JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` tcuis
        ON t.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id and tt.term_id IN (".$cuis.") 
     WHERE tarea.description = 'XYZ' and 
           tcuis.descriptoin = 'ABC'
  GROUP BY t.object_id 
     LIMIT 0,7 ;
```

Also, you can change the `left join`s to `inner join`s -- which the `where` clause does anyway.  The `left join`s would be useful for "or" conditions rather than "and" conditions.

Comment: what to put in place of 'XYZ' and 'ABC' ? As the description field is empty.

Comment: @YaarMallangJeha . . . Your query says "have the area 'XYZ' and cuisine 'ABC'".  So use whatever field has those values.  I just guessed description because it is not obvious.